# Neovim takes so long to source ruby.vim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, filetype-ruby

After noticing some lag that only happens when I use neovim to open Ruby files, I have debugged it and find the result quite interesting (from ms 255 to ms 1294):

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.011  000.011: --- NVIM STARTING ---
000.779  000.768: locale set
001.476  000.697: inits 1
001.495  000.019: window checked
002.105  000.610: parsing arguments
002.110  000.005: expanding arguments
002.217  000.107: inits 2
002.547  000.330: init highlight
003.332  000.246  000.246: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
003.471  000.510  000.264: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
032.373  028.808  028.808: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.vim
032.458  029.613  000.295: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
035.139  002.590  002.590: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/autoload/plug.vim
040.513  002.977  002.977: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/ftoff.vim
066.653  024.721  024.721: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.vim
066.877  000.053  000.053: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin.vim
067.060  000.042  000.042: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/indent.vim
067.277  000.052  000.052: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.vim
067.456  000.047  000.047: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin.vim
067.682  000.030  000.030: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/indent.vim
068.327  000.178  000.178: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
069.049  000.160  000.160: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
069.383  000.156  000.156: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
076.225  007.741  007.425: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nord-vim/colors/nord.vim
076.373  073.635  005.590: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/init.vim
076.379  000.198: sourcing vimrc file(s)
077.077  000.201  000.201: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/autoload/gitgutter/utility.vim
077.502  000.133  000.133: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/autoload/gitgutter/highlight.vim
078.311  001.671  001.337: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/plugin/gitgutter.vim
078.910  000.475  000.475: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-surround/plugin/surround.vim
079.628  000.576  000.576: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/lightline.vim/plugin/lightline.vim
080.824  001.015  001.015: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.fzf/plugin/fzf.vim
081.703  000.757  000.757: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/fzf.vim/plugin/fzf.vim
081.930  000.105  000.105: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-startify/plugin/startify.vim
082.597  000.143  000.143: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree.vim
083.686  000.470  000.470: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/path.vim
083.884  000.111  000.111: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_controller.vim
084.039  000.077  000.077: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_item.vim
084.217  000.100  000.100: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/key_map.vim
084.498  000.203  000.203: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/bookmark.vim
084.792  000.213  000.213: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_file_node.vim
085.240  000.365  000.365: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_dir_node.vim
085.512  000.191  000.191: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/opener.vim
085.811  000.218  000.218: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/creator.vim
085.937  000.047  000.047: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/flag_set.vim
086.144  000.130  000.130: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/nerdtree.vim
086.586  000.365  000.365: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/ui.vim
086.696  000.026  000.026: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/event.vim
086.813  000.040  000.040: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/notifier.vim
087.268  000.366  000.366: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim
103.030  000.101  000.101: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
103.591  000.511  000.511: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
104.421  000.693  000.693: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-nerdtree-tabs/nerdtree_plugin/vim-nerdtree-tabs.vim
104.617  022.568  018.197: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
109.363  004.623  004.623: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nerdcommenter/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim
116.162  006.246  006.246: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-fugitive/plugin/fugitive.vim
117.079  000.304  000.304: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale.vim
118.349  000.205  000.205: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/toggle.vim
118.826  002.472  001.964: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/plugin/ale.vim
119.636  000.095  000.095: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/provider/pythonx.vim
199.542  080.219  080.124: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/provider/python.vim
239.339  000.269  000.269: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/remote/host.vim
239.441  039.710  039.441: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/provider/python3.vim
239.785  120.779  000.850: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/plugin/youcompleteme.vim
240.366  000.036  000.036: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gui_shim.vim
240.723  000.317  000.317: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim
240.791  000.027  000.027: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/health.vim
240.899  000.071  000.071: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/man.vim
241.515  000.576  000.576: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/matchit.vim
241.803  000.190  000.190: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim
242.308  000.457  000.457: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
242.982  000.192  000.192: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/remote/define.vim
243.066  000.503  000.311: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.local/share/nvim/rplugin.vim
243.074  000.713  000.210: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/rplugin.vim
243.140  000.019  000.019: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/rrhelper.vim
243.292  000.108  000.108: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/shada.vim
243.373  000.032  000.032: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/spellfile.vim
243.563  000.146  000.146: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
243.700  000.092  000.092: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/tohtml.vim
243.771  000.026  000.026: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/tutor.vim
244.002  000.182  000.182: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
244.013  003.354: loading plugins
244.111  000.098: loading packages
244.326  000.049  000.049: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/after/plugin/ale.vim
244.343  000.183: loading after plugins
244.351  000.008: inits 3
245.530  001.179: reading ShaDa
247.687  002.156: clearing screen
254.170  002.672  002.672: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/ruby.vim
255.154  000.225  000.225: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/provider/ruby.vim
1294.907  1040.213  1039.989: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/ruby.vim
1296.065  000.501  000.501: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/indent/ruby.vim
1296.577  000.386  000.386: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/lightline.vim/autoload/lightline.vim
1297.137  000.048  000.048: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/lightline.vim/autoload/lightline/tab.vim
1297.633  000.193  000.193: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/lightline.vim/autoload/lightline/colorscheme.vim
1298.123  000.854  000.661: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/nord-vim/autoload/lightline/colorscheme/nord.vim
1301.287  000.062  000.062: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/events.vim
1301.666  000.200  000.200: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/util.vim
1302.204  000.291  000.291: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/linter.vim
1302.882  000.366  000.366: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/ale_linters/ruby/brakeman.vim
1303.305  000.368  000.368: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/ale_linters/ruby/rails_best_practices.vim
1303.730  000.371  000.371: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/ale_linters/ruby/reek.vim
1304.144  000.360  000.360: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/ale_linters/ruby/rubocop.vim
1304.549  000.354  000.354: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/ale_linters/ruby/ruby.vim
1307.615  000.051  000.051: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/pattern_options.vim
1309.866  000.999  000.999: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/engine.vim
1310.342  000.118  000.118: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/handlers/rubocop.vim
1310.679  000.072  000.072: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/history.vim
1311.167  000.058  000.058: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/command.vim
1326.470  000.765  000.765: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/job.vim
1349.343  052.544: opening buffers
1350.024  000.365  000.365: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/autoload/gitgutter.vim
1351.377  000.145  000.145: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/autoload/gitgutter/async.vim
1351.682  000.151  000.151: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/autoload/gitgutter/debug.vim
1377.794  021.768  021.768: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-gitgutter/autoload/gitgutter/diff.vim
1400.106  028.334: BufEnter autocommands
1400.123  000.017: editing files in windows
1401.999  001.034  001.034: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/autoload/youcompleteme.vim
1525.528  000.147  000.147: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/provider.vim
1605.589  204.286: VimEnter autocommands
1605.597  000.008: before starting main loop
1606.038  000.176  000.176: sourcing /Users/huyvo/.config/nvim/plugged/ale/autoload/ale/cursor.vim
1623.767  017.995: first screen update
1623.771  000.004: --- NVIM STARTED ---
```

Sourcing ruby.vim takes very long time to finish, I don't think that the root cause is because of my settings and plugins, but because neovim somehow just doesn't know where my ruby path is.

Adding `let g:ruby_path="/usr/bin/ruby"` to the configuration file does solve the lagging problem, but it raises another question: what's wrong with neovim and ruby path? And if neovim doesn't know where Ruby path is at the beginning, why does it take so long to find the path?

I used to look for the `init.vim` of other Ruby developers. None of them explicitly set ruby path in their config. If they don't have the lagging problem then why me?

My configuration can be found at https://github.com/huyvohcmc/dotfiles/blob/master/init.vim

Update:
Here is my result when I run `checkhealth` fyi:

```
health#nvim#check
========================================================================
## Configuration
  - OK: no issues found

## Performance
  - OK: Build type: Release

## Remote Plugins
  - OK: Up to date

## terminal
  - INFO: key_backspace (kbs) terminfo entry: key_backspace=^H
  - INFO: key_dc (kdch1) terminfo entry: key_dc=\E[3~
  - INFO: $XTERM_VERSION=''
  - INFO: $VTE_VERSION=''
  - INFO: $SSH_TTY=''

health#provider#check
========================================================================
## Clipboard (optional)
  - OK: Clipboard tool found: pbcopy

## Python 2 provider (optional)
  - INFO: Using: g:python_host_prog = "/usr/local/bin/python"
  - INFO: Executable: /usr/local/bin/python
  - INFO: Python2 version: 2.7.14
  - INFO: python-neovim version: 0.2.4
  - OK: Latest python-neovim is installed: 0.2.4

## Python 3 provider (optional)
  - INFO: Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/usr/local/bin/python3"
  - INFO: Executable: /usr/local/bin/python3
  - INFO: Python3 version: 3.6.4
  - INFO: python3-neovim version: 0.2.4
  - OK: Latest python3-neovim is installed: 0.2.4

## Ruby provider (optional)
  - INFO: Ruby: ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin17]
  - INFO: Host: /Users/huyvo/.rbenv/shims/neovim-ruby-host
  - OK: Latest "neovim" gem is installed: 0.7.1

## Node provider (optional)
  - INFO: Node: v8.9.4
  - INFO: Host: /Users/huyvo/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/neovim-node-host
  - OK: Latest "neovim" npm is installed: 3.5.2
```

Comment: what's the result of `:CheckHealth` command?  that's first thing to do when you have trouble with Neovim plugins

Comment: @number5 `checkhealth` show no warnings or errors, I'll update it to the  question.

Comment: my gut feel is this has something to do with your rbenv setup ```- INFO: Ruby: ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin17]
  - INFO: Host: /Users/huyvo/.rbenv/shims/neovim-ruby-host``` . 
Maybe try to use Ruby 2.4 as your host to see if it make any difference, if not I suggest you create a github issue on neovim project

Comment: @number5 It's definitely `rbenv` that cause the lagging - switch to `rvm` solved the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about Vim, but rather a question about Ruby/rbenv.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Are you seriously consider [neovim] is not belong to vi.stachexchange.com?

Comment: I can't vote to mark this question back on topic, would if I could. Both rbenv & ruby are used commonly enough (w/ vi/vim/neovim) that this seems on-topic & solution for someone who is seeing similar slowness. The ruby ft plugins in vim have rbenv detection in them, which makes this a vim plugin related question.